# How do you find the licenses for everything installed on your system?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to write a script that outputs the license for every software package installed on my system.

Using `dpkg --get-selections` I am able to get list of everything installed. However, I don't see a way to get the license information for each package. For example, I can use `aptitude show` to get the properties of each package, but that does not include the license:

```
$ aptitude show apache2
Package: apache2
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.6
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Uncompressed Size: 36.9k
Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.6) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.6) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.6) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.6),
         apache2.2-common (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.6)
Provided by: apache2-mpm-event, apache2-mpm-itk, apache2-mpm-prefork, apache2-mpm-worker
Description: Apache HTTP Server metapackage
 The Apache Software Foundation's goal is to build a secure, efficient and extensible HTTP server as standards-compliant open source software. The result has long been the
 number one web server on the Internet. 

 It features support for HTTPS, virtual hosting, CGI, SSI, IPv6, easy scripting and database integration, request/response filtering, many flexible authentication schemes, and
 more.
Homepage: http://httpd.apache.org/
```

Is there a third-party repository that correlates the license to each package?

It sounds painful to download every source package and inspect it for licensing information, but maybe that's the best way.

Comment: This appears non-trivial at this point. Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/88403/how-to-list-all-my-packages-from-command-line-which-can-show-package-name-licen  See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/334189/get-a-list-of-the-licences-of-all-packages-on-ubuntu-system

Comment: See also now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044841/how-to-list-all-installed-packages-licences-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all my packages from command line which can show package name, license, source url, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88403/how-to-list-all-my-packages-from-command-line-which-can-show-package-name-licen)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. (results in `~/licenses.txt` with all the licenses that exist in `/usr/share/doc`)

```
$ packages=`dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ print $1 }'`
$ for package in $packages; do echo "$package: "; cat /usr/share/doc/$package/copyright; echo ""; echo ""; done > ~/licenses.txt
```

Comment: This is very roundabount.  Simply `grep '^' /usr/share/doc/*/copyright` will get you much the same information, or `tail -n 10000 /usr/share/doc/*/copyright` if you don't want the file name prefix on every line.

Answer (score 15):

In 2012, Debian released the document [Machine-readable debian/copyright](http://dep.debian.net/deps/dep5/) which will make licenses readable in the future. Currently, not all packages use this format. The command

```
grep -h '^License:' /usr/share/doc/*/copyright | sort -i | uniq -ic | sort -n
```

still returns a lot of garbage. For a better output you probably need a tool which parses each file depending on the `Format:` field value.

A completely different way is the file structure in `/usr/share/common-licenses/` (thx to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884753/license-info-of-a-deb-package#1884785). It lists the main licenses used in debian-based distributions (and contains their license texts). This list is provided by the package `base-files` and is *not* linked to the list of installed packages, but it's probably enough information for the average boss/customer.

```
ls /usr/share/common-licenses/
Apache-2.0  BSD   GFDL-1.2  GPL    GPL-2  LGPL    LGPL-2.1
Artistic    GFDL  GFDL-1.3  GPL-1  GPL-3  LGPL-2  LGPL-3
```

**Update**
I just published a simple command-line solution which extracts the license information from the copyright files with a lot of heuristics. https://github.com/daald/dpkg-licenses. Feel free to try it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

I just stumble on dpkg-licenses (https://github.com/daald/dpkg-licenses).

Just clone the repo

> git clone https://github.com/daald/dpkg-licenses.git

Then

> ./dpkg-licenses > licenses.txt

And you have the best of today softwares installed, versions and licenses tabular list you can dream of...

Comment: @Daniel Alder already referred to the same link in another answer https://askubuntu.com/a/620069/24203 and he seems to be the author of the tool :)