# Any way to tabulate the package name and license avail on Ubuntu repo?

Tags: apt, scripts, license, gpl

I need to create a table with all installable packages on first column and its license in the second.

e.g.:

- Gedit   |   GPL

Comment: Installable? Installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apt doesn't really support licencing queries like that but you always try `aptitude -F "%p %s" search "?not(?installed)"` That will tell you what section of the repository it's in.

There is also

> packages=`dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ print $1 }'`
>   for package in $packages; do echo "$package: "; cat /usr/share/doc/$package/copyright;echo ""; echo ""; done > ~/licenses.txt

From [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247757/how-do-you-find-the-licenses-for-everything-installed-on-your-system)